feign.codec.EncodeException: Error converting request body
Tried to upload a file via Rest request using MultiPartFile. Getting the request in the controller in App A, which calls service, which then calls FeignClient to invoke different REST endpoint in App B.
Controller class
@RestController("strategy")
@Validated
public class StrategyController {
  private final StrategyService strategyService;

  public StrategyController(StrategyService strategyService) {
    this.strategyService = strategyService;
  }

  @RequestMapping(path = ASSORT_STRAT_UPLOAD_REQUEST, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> upload(MultipartFile file) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(strategyService.upload(file));
  }

Service class
@Service
public class StrategyServiceImpl implements StrategyService {
  private final strategyServiceRestClient strategyServiceRestClient;

  public StrategyServiceImpl(strategyServiceRestClient strategyServiceRestClient) {
    this.strategyServiceRestClient = strategyServiceRestClient;
  }

  @Override
  public String upload(MultipartFile file) {
    return strategyServiceRestClient.uploadRequest(file);
  }
}

Feign Client
@FeignClient(value = "strategy", url = "${strategy-service-url}", configuration = StrategyServiceFeignConfig.class)
public interface StrategyServiceRestClient {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = KimsBffConstants.ASSORT_STRAT_UPLOAD_REQUEST)
  @HandleFeignException(HandleFeignClientException.class)
  String uploadRequest(@RequestPart MultipartFile file);
}

Seeing the following exception when it calls strategyServiceRestClient.uploadRequest(file);
Caused by:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MultipartFile resource [file] cannot be resolved to URL 
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getURL(AbstractResource.java:113)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource.getURI(AbstractResource.java:123)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeOptionalFields(MapSerializer.java:869)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:760)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:720)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:35)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.checkAndWrite(SpringEncoder.java:217)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.encodeWithMessageConverter(SpringEncoder.java:146)

This is the request/response from postman


Thank yo. I've added the screenshot of my postman test to the actual question

please add the complete request headers (not as screenshot please) or the complete raw request. Response headers might also be useful, but you can try without for now.

You should probably add consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE to both controller and client.

Testing without specifying media type, verifies that requests will fail. Hence please try this.
@FeignClient(
        value = "strategy", 
        url = "${strategy-service-url}", 
        configuration = StrategyServiceFeignConfig.class)
public interface StrategyServiceRestClient {

    @PostMapping(
            value = KimsBffConstants.ASSORT_STRAT_UPLOAD_REQUEST,
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
    )
    @HandleFeignException(HandleFeignClientException.class)
    String uploadRequest(@RequestPart MultipartFile file);
}

The answer is written without knowledge of StrategyServiceFeignConfig and the @HandleFeignException annotation, both of which are not mentioned in the question.
